# Fourier transformation: Delta

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

[image]

I need to find the FT of this function. Here is my attempt:
$$H(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} ke^{-2 \pi i f t}dt$$
We know that $\delta(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2 \pi i f t} df$, the part with sin in this integration vanish, so that, and knowing that cos is a even function, we can write $\delta(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2 \pi i f t} df = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 \pi i f t} df$.

Now, for example, $\int_{-a}^{a}x^2 = 2\int_{0}^{a}x^2$. So we can write the delta above as $\delta(t) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2 \pi i f t} df = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2 \pi i f t} df$.

Putting this in the first formula $$H(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} ke^{-2 \pi i f t}dt.$$

$$H(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} ke^{-2 \pi i f t} dt = k \delta(f) /2$$

Now, I know this isn't right, but I don't know where is my error and what should I do.

Comment: You are consider the function $f$ as an integrand. That's not correct the Fourier transform of $f$ is $H(f)(\xi)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i \xi x} dx $.

Comment: @PabloHerrera Hello. What do you mean? I use the equation you show above with f(x) = k, and calling x =t.

Comment: @LSS The Fourier transform runs over $\mathbb{R}$ and not just $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @vitamind yes but the function is zero for R-

Comment: @LSS Right. Have you looked at my answer? Does it help? If you have any further questions let me know in the comments so that I can expand my answer if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We can express $h(t)$ with the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$ as follows
$$\frac{k\,(\operatorname{sgn}(t)+1)}{2}.$$
Now take the Fourier-Transform (normalization=$1$, oscillatory factor =$-2\pi$),
$$\mathcal{F}\{h(t)\}(\omega)=\frac{k}{2}\mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{sgn}(t)\}(\omega)+\frac{k}{2}\mathcal{F}\{1\}(\omega).$$
The Fourier transform of the sign function can be evaluated by observing that $\operatorname{sgn}'(t)=2\delta(t)$. The Fourier transform of $1$ is well-known. This yields
$$\mathcal{F}\{h(t)\}(\omega)=\frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{1}{i\pi \omega}+\delta(\omega)\right).$$